# Dotnet Api Auto Mapper on Many to Many Relation won't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have three classes for many to relation in dotnet core Api. Here's how they look like ;

```cs
public class Job
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(70)]
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string Detail { get; set; }

    public int Urgency { get; set; }
    public bool IsFinished { get; set; } = false;
    public List<User_Has_Job> user_Has_jobs { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Mail { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Passwd { get; set; }

    public List<User_Has_Job> user_Has_jobs { get; set; }
}

public class User_Has_Job
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public Job job { get; set; }
}
```

And here is how my context class looks like ;

```cs
public class TodoApiContext : DbContext
{
    public TodoApiContext(DbContextOptions<TodoApiContext> opt) : base(opt)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ManyToManyRelationshipConfiguration(modelBuilder);
    }

    private void ManyToManyRelationshipConfiguration(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User_Has_Job>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.JobId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<User_Has_Job>()
            .HasOne(am => am.job)
            .WithMany(a => a.user_Has_jobs)
            .HasForeignKey(am => am.JobId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User_Has_Job>()
            .HasOne(am => am.user)
            .WithMany(m => m.user_Has_jobs)
            .HasForeignKey(am => am.UserId);
    }
    public DbSet<User> users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Job> jobs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User_Has_Job> user_Has_jobs { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the mapping i am currently using ;

```cs
public TodoMapping()
{
    CreateMap<UserCreateDto, User>();

    CreateMap<User, UserReadDto>().ForMember(
        dto => dto.user_Has_jobs, 
        t => t.MapFrom(h => h.user_Has_jobs.Select(cs => job)));


    CreateMap<User, UserUpdateDto>();

    CreateMap<UserUpdateDto, User>();

    CreateMap<JobUpdateDto, Job>();
    CreateMap<Job, JobUpdateDto>();
    CreateMap<JobCreateDto, Job>();
    CreateMap<Job, JobReadDto>();
}
```

And these are my data transfer objects;

```cs
public class UserReadDto
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Mail { get; set; }

    public List<JobReadDto> user_Has_jobs { get; set; }

    public UserReadDto()
    {

    }
}
```

This is how i configure mapper ;

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IUserRepo, SqlUserRepo>();
    services.AddScoped<IJobRepo, SqlJobRepo>();
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddDbContext<TodoApiContext>(
        opt => opt.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("TodoApiConnection")));

    services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
}
```

Even though there is a job recorded for the user with id 1;

[DB screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPe5f.png)

this is  the output i am receiving after sending a GET request via postman ;

> {
> "id": 1,
> "name": "s",
> "lastName": "s",
> "mail": "s",
> "user_Has_jobs": []
> }

As you can see "user_Has_jobs" is not null, but it is completely empty. I have tried changing the mapping a lot of times but so for it just doesn't work. Where do you think problem might be at ?

**Thanks in advance for you time and help.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. So it looks like i have to use Include() function and include the relation while trying to fetch results from the database like this ;

await _context.users.Include(u => u.user_Has_jobs).ThenInclude(s => s.job).FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == addJobToUserDto.UserId);

if i use this code instead of fetching results directly and then map it to a dto, then each result object will have it's job as a list.